# The best practice for not null if statements

Tags: php

I've been writing my "If this variable is not empty" statements like so:

```
if ($var != '') {
// Yup
}
```

But I've asked if this is correct, it hasn't caused a problem for me. Here is the answer I found online:

```
if (!($error == NULL)) {
/// Yup
}
```

This actually looks longer than my approach, but is it better? If so, why?

Comment: [is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) can be good to use to.

Comment: `if(empty($var))` or `if(is_null($var))` seems to be better for me

Comment: I agree with kingdm.  `empty()` checks for null or empty values.

Comment: Are you checking specifically for null, or all "falsey" values? (i.e. null, false, 0, '', etc.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Rather than:

```
if (!($error == NULL))
```

Simply do:

```
if ($error)
```

One would think that the first is more clear, but it's actually more misleading. Here's why:

```
$error = null;

if (!($error == NULL)) {
    echo 'not null';
}
```

This works as expected. However, the next five values will have the same and (to many, unexpected) behavior:

```
$error = 0;
$error = array();
$error = false;
$error = '';
$error = 0.0;
```

The second conditional `if ($error)` makes it more clear that *type casting* is involved.

If the programmer wanted to require that the value actually be `NULL`, he should have used a strict comparison, i.e., `if ($error !== NULL)`

Comment: Do note that you might get errors with the if ($error) approach, if the variable you're trying to check does not exist and is therefore null.

Answer (score 1):

It is good to know exactly what is in your variable, especially if you are checking for uninitialized vs null or na vs true or false vs empty or 0.

Therefore, as mentioned by webbiedave, if checking for null, use

```
$error !== null
$error === null
is_null($error)
```

if checking for initilized, as shibly said

```
isset($var)
```

if checking for true or false, or 0, or empty string

```
$var === true
$var === 0
$var === ""
```

I only use empty for ''s and nulls since string functions tend to be inconsistent.  If checking for empty

```
empty($var)
$var  // in a boolean context

// This does the same as above, but is less clear because you are 
// casting to false, which has the same values has empty, but perhaps
// may not one day.  It is also easier to search for bugs where you
// meant to use ===
$var == false
```

If semantically uninitialized is the same as one of the values above, then initialize the variable at the beginning to that value.

```
$var = ''
...  //some code

if ($var === '') blah blah.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why just don't

```
if (!$var)
```

Comment: The variable might exist though

Comment: so what? your questions didn't specify that

Comment: Won't work for `int` when the value is 0. An `if(0)` will return false.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$foo = NULL;
var_dump(is_null($inexistent), is_null($foo));

?>
```

Another:

```
<?php

$var = '';

// This will evaluate to TRUE so the text will be printed.
if (isset($var)) {
    echo "This var is set so I will print.";
}
?>
```

To check if it's empty:

```
<?php
$var = 0;

// Evaluates to true because $var is empty
if (empty($var)) {
    echo '$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
}

// Evaluates as true because $var is set
if (isset($var)) {
    echo '$var is set even though it is empty';
}
?>
```